# Some Object of a class can have a particular behavior but others doesn't

Tags: java, design-patterns

How can i design this particular Situation.

[image: Basic Diagram of my problem.]

Problem is :

1. if i implement Swim in Bird and add diveNow() behaviour to "fly high" but it is not desired since all birds can't fly.

in other words "Some objects can do that and some can't and both belongs to the same class.

Can i use Strategy Pattern. How?
What if i have a huge set of behaviors [Interfaces] having same kind of problem.

another case(if i override flyNow() in Animal 
but ofcourse some animals can fly (FLYING MOBULAS,FLYING LEMURS.)

Comment: You can extend the class `bird` to have `non-flight` and `flight` birds or you can even go into more detail and extend the class `bird` for every type of `bird`...You could make `bird` an `abstract` class.

Comment: The strategy is if you use `bird` that can fly but lately you you find that `plane` can also fly and you can replace the `bird` with the `plane`.

Comment: @brso05 but what if i have a set of behaviors for same situation.(running,walk,etc....)

Comment: @AsSiDe not sure what you mean? In your `non-flight` class just override the parent class method `flynow()` to do whatever you want for a `non-flight` bird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate animals and their behaviors:

```
interface Animal {}

class Bird implements Animal {}

abstract class AbstractBehavior {
   protected final Animal animal;
   Behavior(Animal animal) {
      this.animal = animal;
   }
}

class SwimImpl extends AbstractBehavior implements Swim {
   SwimImpl(Animal animal) {
      super(animal);
   }
   void swim() { System.out.println(animal + " is swimming."); }
}

class FlyImpl implements Fly {
   FlyImpl(Animal animal) {
      super(animal);
   }
   void fly() { System.out.println(animal + " is flying."); }
}
```

Then compose them any way you like:

```
class SwimFly implements Swim, Fly {
   private Swim swim;
   private Fly fly;

   SwimFly(Animal animal) {
      this.swim = new SwimImpl(animal);
      this.fly= new FlyImpl(animal);
   }

   void swim() { swim.swim(); }
   void fly() { fly.fly(); }
}

Bird duck = new Bird();
SwimFly duckBehavior = new SwimFly(duck);
duckBehavior.swim();
duckBehavior.fly();

Bird penguin = new Bird();
Swim penguinBehavior = new SwimImpl(penguin);
penguinBehavior.swim();
```

Basically, this is the [Bridge](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge) design pattern which prevents the explosion of number of subclasses for each possible combination of animals and behaviors.

A nice illustration from the linked page:

[image: Bridge design pattern]

Answer (score 4):

Not all birds can fly, so don't implement `Fly` there:

```
class Bird {}
```

Some birds however can:

```
class FlyingBird extends Bird implements Fly {}
```

Ducks are birds which can fly and swim. Two possibilities (both have the same effect, that the duck is a bird which can fly and swim):

```
class Duck extends Bird implements Fly, Swim {}
class Duck extends FlyingBird implements Swim {}
```

Penguins are birds which can swim, but not fly:

```
class Penguin extends Bird implements Swim {}
```

Ostriches can neither fly nor swim (AFAIK):

```
class Ostrich extends Bird {}
```

Comment: Please note that `Bird` or `FlyingBird` could also be interfaces or `abstract` classes (if they have fields).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the Strategy pattern can be useful here, but it seems that an anonymous class, where you can implement `flyNow()` and `diveNow()`:

```
Bird divingCapableBird = new Bird() {
    void flyNow() {

    }

    void diveNow() {

    }
};
```

The problem with this approach is that statements like `divingCapableBird instanceof Swim` will return `false`, because the type of `divingCapableBird` doesn't implement the `Swim` interface.

In order to solve this, you can implement a class, which implements `Swim` and `extends Bird` and will expose both of the methods:

```
class DivingCapableBird extends Bird implements Swim {
    //methods here
}
```

However, there's another issue this structure, too - now it turns out that `DivingCapableBird` is not an `Animal`.

The root of all evil here is that `Animal` should not implement both of the `Swim` and `Fly` interfaces.

`Animal` should rather be a top-level (`abstract`) class, while the interfaces should be implemented by specific sub-classes of `Animal`.

So, what you should have is:

```
interface Swim {
    void diveNow();
}

interface Fly {
    void flyNow();
}

abstract class Animal {
   //some common animal features go here
}

class Bird implements Fly {
    //implement methods
}

class DivingCapableBird extends Bird implement Swim {
    //implement methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go and make use of some composition. If you separate those behaviours in proper classes, you can switch implementations freely even between members of the same class.

This is also linked to your strategy pattern. You can have something like this:

```
public interface Behaviour {

    void act();

}

public class FlightBehaviour implements Behaviour {

    public void act() {
      System.out.println("I am flying");
    }

}

public class FlightlessBehaviour implements Behaviour {

    public void act() {
        System.out.println("I don't feel like flying, although I have wings");
    }

}
```

Then you can composition as many behaviours as you want in your Animal class hierarchy. This can get pretty complicated with animals with multiple behaviours and stuff like this, but if you plan it carefully, I think you might make use of it.